# Clickable Link in Datatable RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have am trying to add clickable links to a datatable in RMarkdown rendered in HTML.  I am using the code here,

````
```{r}

balt_tweets_short$clickable_tweet_link <- paste0("<a 
href='",balt_tweets_short$id,"'>",paste0("https://twitter.com/statuses
/",balt_tweets_short$id),"</a>")

tweet_table <- datatable(balt_tweets_short,
                     options = list(pageLength = 5),
                     escape = F)
tweet_table

```
````

which seems to work ok but when I try and click on one of the links in the browser
[image]

I get an error which says that the file could not be found and it shows a file path to the current working directory ending with the tweet id, i.e. "baltimore/8244520385...." etc

Why does the clickable link refer to the local filepath and not the actual URL?

Thanks

Comment: I think you may want: `balt_tweets_short$clickable_tweet_link <- paste0("<a 
href='https://twitter.com/statuses/",balt_tweets_short$id,"'>", balt_tweets_short$id,"</a>")`. The `href` in your link as you've written it ought to be prefixed with `https://...`, otherwise, your browser won't understand that you mean to look outside of your local file system.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much kind Sir!